# How to td id create depend on the ternary operator?

Tags: php, html-table, codeigniter-3, ternary-operator

```
  $orientationData = explode('_', $generate_table['orientation']);
  foreach ($orientationData as $orientationData1) {
     $get_ori= $this->o->get_orientation($orientationData1);
     $table_row[$td++] = array('data' => $get_ori, 'style' => 'text-align:center;','class'=>'editable', $orientationData1>0?'id'=>$orientationData1);
  }
```

`$orientationData` is like 1,2,3,4,0,0,0,8,9;
when given `'id'=>$orientationData1` id names are generated as  1,2,3,4,0,0,0,8,9
I want it generated without zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_filter()`(http://php.net/array_filter) to remove 0's from an array.  If you don't provide a callback to the function it removes 0's and 'false' values.

```
  $orientationData = explode('_', $generate_table['orientation']);
  $orientationData = array_filter($orientationData);
  foreach ($orientationData as $orientationData1) {
     $get_ori= $this->o->get_orientation($orientationData1);
     $table_row[$td++] = array('data' => $get_ori, 'style' => 'text-align:center;','class'=>'editable', $orientationData1>0?'id'=>$orientationData1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($orientationData as $orientationData1) {
    $get_ori= $this->o->get_orientation($orientationData1);
    if($orientationData1>0){
        $table_row[$td++] = array('data' => $get_ori, 'style' => 'text-align:center;','class'=>'editable','id'=>$orientationData1);
    }else{
        $table_row[$td++] = array('data' => $get_ori, 'style' => 'text-align:center;','class'=>'editable');
    }
}
```

these result ok.. please tell me another methods?